# Using MTL/Boost Library Mac Terminal C++

Tags: c++, macos, boost, image-stitching

To be precise, I'm attempting to run this excellent project: https://github.com/ppwwyyxx/panorama

I'm using a modern mac.

The issue is that I can't seem to get my computer to properly include the MTL library. I'm stuck with the endless error of:

```
$ make
[cc] matrix.cc ...
matrix.cc:5:10: fatal error: 'boost/numeric/mtl/mtl.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/numeric/mtl/mtl.hpp>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [obj/matrix.o] Error 1
```

I've tried cmake. I've downloaded both the boost and mtl4 libraries. I've put them in my **/usr/local/include** directory. Nothing seems to be working.

Any advice would be excellent, thank you!

Comment: Try to modify the Makefile in `src` and add this on the line [7](https://github.com/ppwwyyxx/panorama/blob/master/src/Makefile#L7):

`-I/usr/local/include`

Comment: @JeanPierreDudey Yeah, that did the trick, post it as an answer for credit--of course now I've got to deal with an old gcc clang linker error :~/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify the Makefile in src and add this on the line [7](https://github.com/ppwwyyxx/panorama/blob/master/src/Makefile#L7) of the Makefile:

```
-I/usr/local/include
```

Comment: Just as an aside for posterity, in order to create the updated makefile, I used TextMate, type 'mate Makefile', then copy-paste the original content plus this line.