# "no such instruction" error when using gcc-4.9 on osx-yosemite

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, clang, image-stitching

For historical reference, here was my last question: [Using MTL/Boost Library Mac Terminal C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793579/using-mtl-boost-library-mac-terminal-c)

After moving past that error, I found I couldn't compile due to an openmp/clang error. So, I installed gcc-4.9 via homebrew.

Now, when I attempt to compile via gcc-4.9 (or g++-4.9) I get

```
$ make
[dep] utils.cc ...
[dep] transformer.cc ...
[dep] sift.cc ...
[dep] planedrawer.cc ...
[dep] panorama.cc ...
[dep] matrix.cc ...
[dep] matcher.cc ...
[dep] main.cc ...
[dep] keypoint.cc ...
[dep] image.cc ...
[dep] filter.cc ...
[dep] debugutils.cc ...
[dep] cylinder.cc ...
[dep] config.cc ...
[dep] color.cc ...
[cc] color.cc ...
/var/folders/12/z2m2xw_d6410xcq6sph3vwf00000gn/T//ccalQtbo.s:11:no such instruction: `vmovsd 16(%rdi), %xmm2'
/var/folders/12/z2m2xw_d6410xcq6sph3vwf00000gn/T//ccalQtbo.s:12:no such instruction: `vmovsd 24(%rdi), %xmm1'
/var/folders/12/z2m2xw_d6410xcq6sph3vwf00000gn/T//ccalQtbo.s:13:no such instruction: `vmovsd 8(%rdi), %xmm3'
/var/folders/12/z2m2xw_d6410xcq6sph3vwf00000gn/T//ccalQtbo.s:14:no such instruction: `vmaxsd %xmm2, %xmm1,%xmm0'
/var/folders/12/z2m2xw_d6410xcq6sph3vwf00000gn/T//ccalQtbo.s:15:no such instruction: `vmaxsd %xmm3, %xmm0,%xmm0'
/var/folders/12/z2m2xw_d6410xcq6sph3vwf00000gn/T//ccalQtbo.s:16:no such instruction: `vucomisd LC0(%rip), %xmm0'
/var/folders/12/z2m2xw_d6410xcq6sph3vwf00000gn/T//ccalQtbo.s:18:no such instruction: `vdivsd %xmm0, %xmm3,%xmm3'
...
make: *** [obj/color.o] Error 1
```

The ellipse to indicate that it continues.

Is there a work around to this gcc-4.9 error? (Every solution to openmp/clang I found was either dangerous or suggested using older gcc/g++'s, thus here we are.)

This question is a duplicate, as has been suggested. The solution to the other problem was changing the way he was calling gcc, which is the same as here. It was just buried in the makefile and through my frustration I missed it.

Comment: @Meshach It's still a duplicate even if you don't know how to apply the solution to your compiler configuration. If you want instructions on changing how gcc is called within this build, then ask a new question with details on the software you are building and its build system.

Comment: … Looking at the two linked questions, you already modified the makefile, and you simply need to do so again to remove `-march=native` on [line 10](https://github.com/ppwwyyxx/panorama/blob/master/src/Makefile#L10).

Comment: @Potatoswatter wow, I'm embarassed. You're quite right.